# MySQL index for only maximum and minimum values

Tags: mysql, indexing, max, query-optimization

I have a huge table with millions of rows which stores the values obtained from some weather stations. Every row contains the station that gathered the value, the metric (for example, temperature, humidity, noise level, etc.), the date and the value itself.

This is its structure:

- `station`: int(8)
- `metric`: int(8)
- `date`: datetime
- `value`: float

And these are the indices I've defined:

- PRIMARY KEY: `station+metric+date`
- KEY: `metrica` (for the foreign key)

Sometimes, I'm interested in retrieving the last time every station has sent some value. Then I use this query:

```
 SELECT station, MAX(date)
 FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY station
```

This query is very slow, as it has to read the entire table. If I add an index for station+date, the query now can use it and it becomes very fast. But the table storage also increases a lot, and for me indexing all date values is not useful, given I'm only interested on the max value.

So my question is if it's possible to create an index that indexes some range, ideally to only keep track of the maximum value.

Comment: You are probably better off storing that information in another table -- say the `Stations` table -- and using a trigger to update the information every times a row is inserted.

Comment: Can you change the PK to `station+date+metric` ? Functionally it would be the same thing but practically it would be (almost) as fast as the situation where you added the extra index.

Comment: @deroby I've tried it, and indeed the query runs instantly. But another frequent query such as "list one week values of temperatura for one station" now executes slower (not so much, around 25% slower). Given that the last one is by far more frequent in my application, I will stay with my previous primary key. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know. But you have alternative solutions.

In other databases I'd suggest a materialized view, but MySQL does not support materialized views ([SO#3991912](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991912/materialized-views-with-mysql)) so you have to create and manage your own aggregate table your self.

If your source table is not updated too frequently a `CREATE TABLE last_observation AS SELECT station, MAX(date) AS date FROM observations GROUP BY station` will do the work. Simply issue the statement before any relevant request.

If your server has enough resources, you can leave the table in [MEMORY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html), to get superfast responses. In that case you need to name explicitly the columns `CREATE TABLE last_observation (station VARCHAR(x), lastDate DATE) ENGINE=MEMORY AS SELECT station, MAX(date) AS lastDate FROM observations GROUP BY station`. Of course this statement should issued routinely each time you open mysql.

If your table is updated frequently, you can manage the content with triggers on the source table ([Full tutorial here](http://www.fromdual.ch/mysql-materialized-views)).

An other solution, on a totally different path, is to use a column oriented database. We used Infobright a few years ago, which has an free community edition, and is totally transparent for you (just install it and use mysql as before).

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(station, date)
```

will handle *that* query efficiently.  Alternatively, you could rearrange the `PRIMARY KEY` to `(station, date, metric)`.

If you also want the temp on that date, then you are into a more complex [*groupwise-max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) .